# Does Eilat belong to Bney Israel?

Tags: history, eretz-yisrael, travel, melachim-kings-book-of, state-of-israel

1 Kings 9:26 "King Solomon made a ship in Etzion Geber, which is beside Eloth on the shore of the Red Sea, in the land of Edom."

Does Eilat (which spelling is also spelled Eloth) belong to "the land of Edom", implying it does not belong to Israel (howbeit it was conquered by Israel, during biblical times)?

I understand that Hashem gave the Land of Canaan to Bney Israel, but did Hashem also give the Land of Edom to Bney Israel?

Which authorities, rabbinical or older, hold this view, that Eilat does or does not belong to Bney Israel, either by conquest or inheritance?

This post assumes that the modern-day Israeli city of Eilat is within the boundary of biblical Eilat. If you think otherwise, mention that in your answer.

The "related" mi yodeya link, about living in Israel and visiting Eilat, has two opposing answers, where one rabbi said, yes; and another rabbi, said no. In both cases, no elaboration is given and/or link is broken.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.34?lang=bi

Comment: Related - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11069/can-someone-who-lives-in-israel-visit-eilat

Comment: This sefaria link does not answer the question, as it only says, "Your southern sector shall extend from the wilderness of Zin alongside Edom."

Comment: This "related" link has two opposing answers, where one rabbi said, yes; and another rabbi, said no.

Comment: @Dov. No. This "related" link has two opposing answers, where one rabbi said, yes; and another rabbi, said no. In both cases, no elaboration is given and/or link is broken.

Comment: @mbloch No. This "related" mi yodeya link, about living in Israel and visiting Eilat, has two opposing answers, where one rabbi said, yes; and another rabbi, said no. In both cases, no elaboration is given and/or link is broken.

Comment: Just because the answers to the other question don't satisfy you doesn't mean it's not a duplicate. If you want a better answer, you can offer a bounty (one you have enough points. If you'd like, I can offer one instead)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can someone who lives in Israel visit Eilat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11069/can-someone-who-lives-in-israel-visit-eilat)

Comment: @Loani you offer a bounty. Thanks.

Comment: Done, good luck!

Comment: @Loani, you wrote, "Just because the answers to the other question don't satisfy you doesn't mean it's not a duplicate." Why should the other question (which is not my question) satisfy me? The answers to that questions, which is not mine, does not answer my question in this post of mine.

Comment: @ninamag my point was that if the other question should garner the same answers as yours (which I think it does), it's a dupe. You seem to be arguing that since none of those answers elaborate on _why_ they say what they say, it doesn't satisfy you and isn't a dupe. That's not true, you just need better answers to that question